# How to show the archive / post type description on Single templates

Tags: custom-post-types, templates, archives, single

I have a Custom Post Type with an archive description. Both the following functions return said description from the `archive-cpt.php` template, as expected:

```
the_archive_description()

echo get_the_post_type_description();
```

How can I get the same description to show on the `single-cpt.php` template?

(ie for every individual post I want to show the description for the archive it belongs to)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Within the loop, you can do it this way, outside of the loop, pass the post ID to `get_post_type` function. :

```
// Within the loop
$cpt = get_post_type_object(get_post_type());

if($cpt !== NULL)
{
    echo $cpt->name;
    echo $cpt->description;
}
```

If you need to see more about `get_post_type_object` you can find it in [codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_type_object).